# Formatting table with jQuery is very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a table that has a toggle to show/hide various rows that match certain criteria and I'm using the following JS to achieve what I want ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYsHL/3/));

```
function resetRows() {
    var i = 1,
        tds;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    $('td').removeClass('even odd');

    $.each($('tr'), function (key, index) {
        // loop through each table row skipping the first row which will be the title
        tds = $(this).find($('td'));
        if ($(this).is(':visible') && key > 0) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                tds.addClass('even');
            } else {
                tds.addClass('odd');
            }
            // find the .index class and reset it's value
            $(this).find($('.index')).html(i);
            i++;
        }
    });
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    console.log('time taken: ' + time);
}

$(function () {

    // show/hide failed
    $('#showHideFails').on('click', function () {
        if ($('.failed').eq(0).is(':visible')) {
            $('.failed, .ins').hide();
            $('.shTxt').html('Show all');
            resetRows();
        } else {
            $('.failed, .ins').show();
            $('.shTxt').html('Hide failed');
            resetRows();
        }
    });

});
```

My problem is that this code is executing very slowly. The js fiddle is relatively quick as my example table only has 15 rows. My actual table has 100 rows, and can be changed to show 1,000 rows.

I've added a console log to test how long it's executing and in the fiddle it's taking ~15ms to hide the rows and ~20-40ms to show the rows again.

On my real table with 100 rows this changes to ~300-450ms to hide and ~500-600ms to show. This figure more than doubles when trying 200 rows (1,200 and 2,00 respectively). When I tried with 1,000 rows my browser nearly crashed.

I tried changing my code so that instead of changing the class names of `td`'s it changed the class names of the `tr`'s as in theory this would mean less processing required for jQuery to handle, however this almost doubled the execution time so I reverted back to `td`'s

Can anyone tell me how to make my code more efficient? It's a little frustrating to get the functionality that I want, only to have it run very slowly.

Comment: You're double wrapping selectors why `$(this).find($('.index'))` or `$(this).find($('td'))`? Also you can just use `.each` instead of `$.each`.

Comment: two things - jquery $.each can be slow when looping through many dom elements (sorry no source for this other than what I've noticed when using it) and also, `console.time('myTime');` and `console.timeEnd('myTime');` can be used to time events and run multiple timers at the same... er... time. I would be tempted to put a timer on each significant block of code and use that to see where the most time is spent, so you can focus on what to refactor. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time

Comment: here is a fork with a few fixes (including @elclanrs suggestion), and some timers - http://jsfiddle.net/FZ7EV/

Comment: @elclanrs I don't know why I was double wrapping...changing that shaved off a good ~150ms on hiding and ~200ms on showing. Changing from `$.each` to `.each` didn't make a difference, however again I'm not sure why i didn't do it the latter way to begin with

Comment: @jammypeach thanks for the `console` timing tips, I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should detach your table from DOM when using this kind of elements iteration. You could then show any message to user like a loader during task.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYsHL/6/

```
function resetRows($table) {
    var $loader = $('<div id="loader"/>').insertBefore($table),
        $tblContent = $table.detach(),
        i = 1,
        trs = $tblContent.find('tr'),
        tds = $tblContent.find('td').removeClass('even odd');
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    $.each(trs, function (key, index) {
        // loop through each table row skipping the first row which will be the title
        var tdsRow = $(this).find('td');

        if (!$(this).data('hidden') && key > 0) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                tdsRow.addClass('even');
            } else {
                tdsRow.addClass('odd');
            }
            // find the .index class and reset it's value
            $(this).find('.index').html(i);
            i++;
            console.log(i);
        }
    });
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    $loader.replaceWith($table);
    console.log('time taken: ' + time);
}

$(function () {

    // show/hide failed
    $('#showHideFails').on('click', function () {
        if ($('.failed').eq(0).is(':visible')) {
            $('.failed, .ins').data('hidden',true).hide();
            $('.shTxt').html('Show all');
            resetRows($('#table'));
        } else {
            $('.failed, .ins').data('hidden',false).show();
            $('.shTxt').html('Hide failed');
            resetRows($('#table'));
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: While this hide/show is much quicker, the re-indexing and row classes are not being applied. I've not come across `.detach()` before, so I'm not too sure why they're not being applied.

Comment: Ha ya, because $(this).is(':visible') cannot be applied to detached elements. Should find a workaround. Look at updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Some code optimization suggestions:

1. usage of `.find()`

   `tds = $(this).find($('td'));` is the same as `tds = $(this).find('td')`

   `$('td')`  causes  jquery to search for *all* table cells in your whole HTML *before doing anything else*

   But what you really want is: All cells for the current row *only* which can be done with $(this).find('td')
2. Remove "dead" code

   Your row-iteration-function does *nothing* if you're in the header-row or if the row has already been hidden. At the moment you're searching for cells in that row even if it is hidden.

   ```
    $.each($('tr'), function (key, index) {
       if (false == $(this).is(':visible') || 0 == key) {
           // skip hidden rows and header row
           return;
       }

       // at this point we know that the current row is visible and not the header row
       tds = $(this).find($('td'));
       ...
    });
   ```
3. Reduce jQuery-selectors

   As far as I can see the selectors are the most cost-intensive part here. While that's not a problem for small data it can effect large data like your table with 1000 rows and such. Try to re-use the selector-results where possible by using a variable.

   Replace $(this) with a variable:

   ```
   var currentRow = $(this);
   currentRow.is(':visible');
   currentRow.find('td');
   ...
   ```

These are my thoughts so far. See this jsfiddle for rewritten code: http://jsfiddle.net/5jVdh/3/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, they also help